# Block Chain Polling/Voting using Honest/Costly Signalling [Why is this wrong, can this system work?]

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, tokens, ether, voting

This Poll measures (Support for X) not (People who support X)

You signal support for a candidate by forfeiting any amount of value to a candidate specific address in return you get...

1. A public and verifiable vote, proof that it effected the outcome of this poll.
2. Reasonable belief that the participates in this poll made an honest choice in their selection with full knowledge of its costs. One rich guy can skew the polls but forfeiture of the underlying value is what keeps the poll as honest as possible. Are you really willing to forfeit X amount to show support for Y candidate? Both lying and telling the truth have the same outcome, you forfeit the value and your vote is recorded. Its in everyone best interest to tell the truth.
3. A free (beer&speech) pseudo-anonymous data set, hosted on the blockchain

Example:
You vote in the poll with your 1cent cryptokitty.

Worse case the crypto kitty market explodes and that specific cat shoots to 1million, you forfeited the value in support of a candidate. (This is why its important to tell the truth)

Best case it goes down to .01cent or stays the same, you have a shit coin out your wallet.

In both cases your vote is recorded on the block chain open for anyone to verify, study, or use as a teaching aid.

You can even vote in the poll using a made up token where the value is only the gas fee and time you spent making it.

I'm trying to make sure my logic is sound.